# HoneyBee Hive View For android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hello all can any one help me to create this view i am able to create this view static but i want this dynamic view , According to the data.Thanks

I have Try this but its seem not working like i want [BeeHive View](https://github.com/shijilkadambath/BeeHiveView)

[image: Honey Bee Hive View]

Comment: Dynamic in what way? Is the number of rows and columns variable?

Comment: yes the number of row and columns are dynamic

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far, and state the difficulties you are facning.

Comment: @RickyMo please check i attach the github project  that i have tried

Comment: I have posted a answer plzz check i implemented on latest version of android studio now you will not get any errors acc. To me. Hope my answer will help you.

Comment: @NishaJain  I already try this code its not working as i want i want bee hive view should be in circle as in design ans the image size should also increase according to the design

Comment: You mean you need bee hive in circle shape instead of hexagon shape and image size should be small?

Comment: yes its should be change accroding to the images like the center one gone bigger and side one gone smaller smaller

Comment: I have added a Image below after made some changes acc. to your requirement.

Comment: @NishaJain thank you very much it really amazing i have just one question what happend if i have 50 images how can i put the invisable and visiale array according to 50 images or 30 images like if i have images list is dynmic

Comment: Welcome Amit Pandey.. You can do it by: Stop making array of invisible, empty and normal to static use for loop (e.g you have 30 images  => 
for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
   if(i % 2 == 0){
      invisible.add(i);
}else if(i % 3 == 0){
     empty.add(i);
}else{
   normal.add(i);
}

This is a dummy example do it by your logic. we don't have need to make static array  we can differentiate according to some logic and make it dynamic.

Comment: But i want to show all 30 images with this dimond shape is it possiable with this loop

Comment: Yes remove array of empty and invisible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241608/discussion-between-nisha-jain-and-amit-pandey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes in layout width and height, add if-else loop for each line.

Output:

[image: BeeHive]

Code of MainActivity.kt file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final Integer[] INVISIBLE = {1,2,6,10,11,19,20,25,29,30};// this array have cell number that hide in view
    private static final Integer[] INEMPTY = {4,5,9,15,16,21,26,28};// cell number that visible but it has no image(empty cell)
    private static final Integer[] NORMAL = {3,7,8,12,13,14,17,18,22,23,24,27};// normal cells

    private LinearLayout l_root;
    private List<CustomShapeImageView> photoViewList;// each cell view
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    private final static ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initImageLoader(this);

        photoViewList=new ArrayList<>();
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.avatar)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.avatar)
                .cacheOnDisk(true).build();

        l_root =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l_root);
        l_root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = 1000;  // device screen width

        //int height = size.y;
        addView(width);
        addImage();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://github.com/NishaJain24/BeeHiveAndroid"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url=v.getTag().toString();
        if (!url.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /** ini universal image loader**/
    public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
        // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you may tune some of them,
        // or you can create default configuration by
        // ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
        // method.
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                //.writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
                .build();
        //Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    }

    /** add image to each normal cells in order**/
    private void addImage() {

        for (int i = 0; (i < ImagesUrl.IMAGEURLS.length && (i < photoViewList.size())); i++) {
            String image = ImagesUrl.IMAGEURLS[i];
            photoViewList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            photoViewList.get(i).setTag(image);
            photoViewList.get(i).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

            final int finalI = i;
            imageLoader.loadImage(image,options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    photoViewList.get(finalI).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

                }
            });
        }

    }

    /** created beehive view here**/
    private void addView(int width){

        int margin=-(width/8)/4;
        width =(width+(width/16))/4;

        photoViewList.clear();
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++) {
            if(j == 0){
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                //ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        width);

                int marginLeft=(j%2 ==0)?(-(width/2)+margin):margin;
                int marginTop=(j !=0)?(-(width/5)):0;


                llParams.setMargins(420, 100, 0,-90 );
                ll.setLayoutParams(llParams);

                for (int i=3;i<4;i++) {
                    int possition=j*4+i;

                    FrameLayout l_farme = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(190, 190);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width - (width/2), width- (width/2));
                    frameParams2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    l_farme.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    ImageView hexagon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    hexagon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                    hexagon.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    CustomShapeImageView photo=new CustomShapeImageView(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.avatar,
                            CustomShapeImageView.Shape.SVG,R.raw.hex);
                    photo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    photo.setLayoutParams(frameParams2);

                    hexagon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hexagon);
                    photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hexagon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (Arrays.asList(INVISIBLE).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(INEMPTY).contains(possition)){
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(NORMAL).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        photo.setTag("-1");
                        photoViewList.add(photo);
                        //photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    l_farme.addView(photo);
                    l_farme.addView(hexagon);
                    ll.addView(l_farme);
                }
                l_root.addView(ll);
            }else if(j == 1){
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                //ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        width);

                int marginLeft=(j%2 ==0)?(-(width/2)+margin):margin;
                int marginTop=(j !=0)?(-(width/5)):0;


                llParams.setMargins(300, 0, 0,0 );
                ll.setLayoutParams(llParams);

                for (int i=2;i<=3;i++) {
                    int possition=j*5+i+1;

                    FrameLayout l_farme = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(220, 220);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width-(width/2), width-(width/2));
                    frameParams2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    l_farme.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    ImageView hexagon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    hexagon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                    hexagon.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    CustomShapeImageView photo=new CustomShapeImageView(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.avatar,
                            CustomShapeImageView.Shape.SVG,R.raw.hex);
                    photo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    photo.setLayoutParams(frameParams2);

                    hexagon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hexagon_small);
                    photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hexagon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (Arrays.asList(INVISIBLE).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(INEMPTY).contains(possition)){
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(NORMAL).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        photo.setTag("-1");
                        photoViewList.add(photo);
                        //photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    l_farme.addView(photo);
                    l_farme.addView(hexagon);
                    ll.addView(l_farme);
                }
                l_root.addView(ll);
            }else if(j == 2){
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                //ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        width);

                int marginLeft=(j%2 ==0)?(-(width/2)+margin):margin;
                int marginTop=(j !=0)?(-(width/5)):0;


                llParams.setMargins(-130, marginTop, 0,0 );
                ll.setLayoutParams(llParams);

                for (int i=0;i<=3;i++) {
                    int possition=j*5+i + 1;

                    FrameLayout l_farme = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(260, 260);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width-(width/2), width-(width/2));
                    frameParams2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    l_farme.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    ImageView hexagon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    hexagon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                    hexagon.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    CustomShapeImageView photo=new CustomShapeImageView(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.avatar,
                            CustomShapeImageView.Shape.SVG,R.raw.hex);
                    photo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    photo.setLayoutParams(frameParams2);

                    hexagon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hexagon_small);
                    photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hexagon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (Arrays.asList(INVISIBLE).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(INEMPTY).contains(possition)){
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(NORMAL).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        photo.setTag("-1");
                        photoViewList.add(photo);
                        //photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    l_farme.addView(photo);
                    l_farme.addView(hexagon);
                    ll.addView(l_farme);
                }
                l_root.addView(ll);
            }else if(j == 3){
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                //ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        width);

                int marginLeft=(j%2 ==0)?(-(width/2)+margin):margin;
                int marginTop=(j !=0)?(-(width/5)):0;


                llParams.setMargins(80, 0, 40,0 );
                ll.setLayoutParams(llParams);

                for (int i=1;i<=3;i++) {
                    int possition=j*6+i+1;

                    FrameLayout l_farme = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(220, 220);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width-(width/2), width-(width/2));
                    frameParams2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    l_farme.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    ImageView hexagon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    hexagon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                    hexagon.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    CustomShapeImageView photo=new CustomShapeImageView(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.avatar,
                            CustomShapeImageView.Shape.SVG,R.raw.hex);
                    photo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    photo.setLayoutParams(frameParams2);

                    hexagon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hexagon_small);
                    photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hexagon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (Arrays.asList(INVISIBLE).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(INEMPTY).contains(possition)){
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(NORMAL).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        photo.setTag("-1");
                        photoViewList.add(photo);
                        //photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    l_farme.addView(photo);
                    l_farme.addView(hexagon);
                    ll.addView(l_farme);
                }
                l_root.addView(ll);
            }else if(j ==  4){
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                //ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        width);

                int marginLeft=(j%2 ==0)?(-(width/2)+margin):margin;
                int marginTop=(j !=0)?(-(width/5)):0;


                llParams.setMargins(230, marginTop, 0,0 );
                ll.setLayoutParams(llParams);

                for (int i=2;i<=3;i++) {
                    int possition=j*6+i-1;

                    FrameLayout l_farme = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(190, 190);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width-(width/2), width-(width/2));
                    frameParams2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    l_farme.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    ImageView hexagon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    hexagon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                    hexagon.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    CustomShapeImageView photo=new CustomShapeImageView(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.avatar,
                            CustomShapeImageView.Shape.SVG,R.raw.hex);
                    photo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    photo.setLayoutParams(frameParams2);

                    hexagon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hexagon_small);
                    photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hexagon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (Arrays.asList(INVISIBLE).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(INEMPTY).contains(possition)){
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(NORMAL).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        photo.setTag("-1");
                        photoViewList.add(photo);
                        //photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    l_farme.addView(photo);
                    l_farme.addView(hexagon);
                    ll.addView(l_farme);
                }
                l_root.addView(ll);
            }else{
                LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                //ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        width);

                int marginLeft=(j%2 ==0)?(-(width/2)+margin):margin;
                int marginTop=(j !=0)?(-(width/5)):0;


                llParams.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, 0,0 );
                ll.setLayoutParams(llParams);

                for (int i=0;i<=5;i++) {
                    int possition=j*5+i +1;

                    FrameLayout l_farme = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, width);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width-(width/2), width-(width/2));
                    frameParams2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    l_farme.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    ImageView hexagon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    hexagon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                    hexagon.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                    CustomShapeImageView photo=new CustomShapeImageView(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.avatar,
                            CustomShapeImageView.Shape.SVG,R.raw.hex);
                    photo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    photo.setLayoutParams(frameParams2);

                    hexagon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hexagon_small);
                    photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    hexagon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (Arrays.asList(INVISIBLE).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(INEMPTY).contains(possition)){
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if (Arrays.asList(NORMAL).contains(possition)){
                        l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        photo.setTag("-1");
                        photoViewList.add(photo);
                        //photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    l_farme.addView(photo);
                    l_farme.addView(hexagon);
                    ll.addView(l_farme);
                }
                l_root.addView(ll);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

BeeHive Result

[image: BeeHive]

MainActivity file:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.meg7.widget.CustomShapeImageView;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.naming.Md5FileNameGenerator;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.QueueProcessingType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.ImageLoadingListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final Integer[] INVISIBLE = {1,2,6,10,11,19,20,25,29,30};// this array have cell number that hide in view
    private static final Integer[] INEMPTY = {4,5,9,15,16,21,26,28};// cell number that visible but it has no image(empty cell)
    private static final Integer[] NORMAL = {3,7,8,12,13,14,17,18,22,23,24,27};// normal cells

    private LinearLayout l_root;
    private List<CustomShapeImageView> photoViewList;// each cell view
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    private final static ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initImageLoader(this);

        photoViewList=new ArrayList<>();
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.avatar)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.avatar)
                .cacheOnDisk(true).build();

        l_root =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l_root);
        l_root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;  // device screen width

        //int height = size.y;
        addView(width);
        addImage();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);//Menu Resource, Menu
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://github.com/NishaJain24/BeeHiveAndroid"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url=v.getTag().toString();
        if (!url.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,url,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /** ini universal image loader**/
    public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
        // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you may tune some of them,
        // or you can create default configuration by
        // ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
        // method.
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                //.writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
                .build();
        //Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

    }

    /** add image to each normal cells in order**/
    private void addImage() {

        for (int i = 0; (i < ImagesUrl.IMAGEURLS.length && (i < photoViewList.size())); i++) {
            String image = ImagesUrl.IMAGEURLS[i];
            photoViewList.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            photoViewList.get(i).setTag(image);
            photoViewList.get(i).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

            final int finalI = i;
            imageLoader.loadImage(image,options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    photoViewList.get(finalI).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

                }
            });
        }

    }

    /** created beehive view here**/
    private void addView(int width){

        int margin=-(width/8)/4;
        width =(width+(width/16))/4;

        photoViewList.clear();
        for (int j=0;j<=5;j++) {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            //ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    width);

            int marginLeft=(j%2 ==0)?(-(width/2)+margin):margin;
            int marginTop=(j !=0)?(-(width/5)):0;


            llParams.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, 0,0 );
            ll.setLayoutParams(llParams);

            for (int i=0;i<=5;i++) {
                int possition=j*5+i +1;

                FrameLayout l_farme = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, width);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams2 = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width-(width/10), width-(width/10));
                frameParams2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                l_farme.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                ImageView hexagon = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                hexagon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                hexagon.setLayoutParams(frameParams);

                CustomShapeImageView photo=new CustomShapeImageView(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.avatar,
                        CustomShapeImageView.Shape.SVG,R.raw.hex);
                photo.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                photo.setLayoutParams(frameParams2);

                hexagon.setImageResource(R.drawable.hexagon);
                photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                hexagon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (Arrays.asList(INVISIBLE).contains(possition)){
                    l_farme.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else if (Arrays.asList(INEMPTY).contains(possition)){
                    photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else if (Arrays.asList(NORMAL).contains(possition)){
                    l_farme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    photo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    photo.setTag("-1");
                    photoViewList.add(photo);
                    //photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                l_farme.addView(photo);
                l_farme.addView(hexagon);
                ll.addView(l_farme);
            }
            l_root.addView(ll);
        }
    }

}
```

Create a java file for storing Image Url

```
public class ImagesUrl {
    public static final String[] IMAGEURLS={
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSa1sjJFmPQiHm0QBL_k6oxOL1ov2LvnriDAw&usqp=CAU",
            "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e9/de/17/e9de175ab3987752fc5d2f49e729d391.jpg",
            "https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/google/noto-emoji-people-face/1024/10135-boy-light-skin-tone-icon.png",
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTKC3g0Ce32Jfxypb9t-KjcfbJ6oZOUCDFrYA&usqp=CAU",
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSmcBIbmP6D2QXQoXyEzZqkPuxDWFLCjYc40A&usqp=CAU",
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTA1ex7y5sJf7RcvxwlHPhfGxEoS0qknjnoBQ&usqp=CAU",
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSekJBSJPfDESTHcDw5cUlp2O3bmJ7zjMp5Wg&usqp=CAU",
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdyenRV1-qC8IV2Utxfm8VQhrXtpVRvpUZ2Q&usqp=CAU",
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQX9iSSdnDdhfRK-H8o4M0XfQxagijAQT83AQ&usqp=CAU",
    };
}
```

Add internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Create menu file and inside menu create a menu resource file

main_menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item  android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="more"/>
</menu>
```

build.gradle(app) file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nishajain.beehiveandroid"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    implementation 'com.mostafagazar:customshapeimageview:1.0.4'
}
```

For raw images and further code used in this example you can refer this link:

[BeeHiveSourceCode](https://github.com/NishaJain24/BeeHiveAndroid)

Comment: you have used normal, inempty and invisible as fixed values, How can it be achieved if the images list is fetched from server so list can have any no. of images.

Comment: We will take only single array normal and loop will be executed  till array of images.length .

Comment: I think you are not getting my point, I want to implement it for more than 50 hexagons images but in same pattern as shown in the question.

Comment: In which image ? available in my answer or black image which is in the question?

Comment: in question @Nisha

Comment: I haven't tried yet.. @Satyam . But I am think that will be solved by some logic like this pattern:          1     11    111   11  1 . Plz try to put some logics with result screen on every change in code.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution to created dynamic number of hexagons with data after getting list from API.

```
arrayList.forEachIndexed { index, domeModel ->

        var rootLayout = ConstraintLayout(this)
        var layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        rootLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams

        var hexagonView = ImageView(this)
        hexagonView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE
        hexagonView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100)
        hexagonView.setImageResource(R.drawable.hexagon)
        hexagonView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255))
        hexagonView.setOnClickListener {

        }

        var singleCell = ImageView(this)
        var imageParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100)
        singleCell.setPadding(25, 25, 25, 25)
        singleCell.layoutParams = imageParams
        singleCell.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
        singleCell.rotation = 270f

        if (index == 0) {
            layoutParams.circleRadius = 0
            layoutParams.circleAngle = 0f
            layoutParams.circleConstraint = binding.tvDome.id

            rootLayout.addView(hexagonView)
            rootLayout.addView(singleCell)
            binding.lRoot.addView(rootLayout)
        }
        if (index!= 0 && index < 7) {
            layoutParams.circleRadius = 120
            layoutParams.circleAngle = -270 + angle * (index - 1)
            layoutParams.circleConstraint = binding.tvDome.id

            rootLayout.addView(hexagonView)
            rootLayout.addView(singleCell)
            binding.lRoot.addView(rootLayout)

        } else if (index in 7..18) {

            layoutParams.circleAngle = angle2 * (index - 1)
            layoutParams.circleConstraint = binding.tvDome.id

            if (index % 2 != 0) {
                layoutParams.circleRadius = 200
            } else {
                layoutParams.circleRadius = 240
            }

            rootLayout.addView(hexagonView)
            rootLayout.addView(singleCell)
            binding.lRoot.addView(rootLayout)

        }
    }
```

xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rotation="90">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/l_root"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context="com.shijil.beehiveview.MainActivity">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp"
                    android:rotation="270"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:id="@+id/tvDome"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

let me know if you face any problem with it